Consider the equation $x^5-5x+1=0$, find the number of real roots and indicate the intervals where these roots belong.
I thought of using $f'(x)=5x^4-5$. Then $5x^4-5=0$ and determine the critical points $1$ and $-1$. I know that between consecutive real roots of $f$ there is a real root of $f′$. So there should be 3 roots on $(-\infty , -1)$, $[-1,1)$ and $[1, \infty)$?

It implies that you may have 3 real roots, one in each of these intervals, not that you must have them

$f(-2)<0,  f(-1)>0 $ what could you say.

You can also check Descartes rule of signs, which indicates that there is at most one negative and two positive real roots.

We know $x\to -\infty; f(x)< 0$. and that $f(-1)>0$ so by IVT there is a root in $(-\infty, -1)$ but as there are no critical points there are no other.  $f(1) < 0$ so by IVT there is a root between in $(-1,1)$ but as there are n critical points it is the only root in the interval.  And we know $x\to +\infty; f(x)> 0$ so there is a root in $(1,\infty)$ and as there are no critical points it is the only root in the interval.  And $f(\pm 1) \ne 0$ so they aren't roots.  So there are exactly $3$ real roots.

"I know that between consecutive real roots of f there is a real root of f'"  That is $\implies$.   Not $\Leftarrow$.  You know that between two real roots there is a real root of $f'$, but you do not know that a real root of $f'$ must lie between two real roots.  All dolphins are mammals but not all mammals are dolphins.

"I know that between consecutive real roots of f there is a real root of f'. So there should be 3 roots"  Not nesc.  Consider $f(x) = x^2 +4$.  $f'(x)=2x$ so there is a critical point at $x=0$ but there are not any real roots on either $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$  Or consider $f(x) = x^3 + 1$.  $f'(x)=3x^2$ so there is a critical point at $x=0$. There is a real root on $(-\infty, 0)$ [namely $x=-1$] but there is no real root on $(0,\infty)$ [because if $x > 0$ then $x^3 + 1> 1$].
